# Kafka Brokers for Hyperledger Fabric could not establish a connection

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I need some assistance with configuring my kafka brokers docker containers for hyperledger fabric. My setup will be a cluster of 4 brokers and I am having an issue when I introduce the second broker. All the brokers are currently sitting on a single machine and I need them to advertise their external address so that my orderers on different machines can discover them.

My compose file with 1 Zookeeper and 1 Broker:

```
version: '2'

services:
  zookeeper0.hyperfabric.xyz:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper
    restart: always
    container_name: zookeeper0.hyperfabric.xyz
    environment:
      - ZOO_SERVERS=server.1=zookeeper0.hyperfabric.xyz:2888:3888
      - ZOO_MY_ID=1
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
      - 2888:2888
      - 3888:3888

  kafka0.hyperfabric.xyz:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-kafka
    restart: always
    container_name: kafka0.hyperfabric.xyz
    environment:
      - KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES=103809024
      - KAFKA_REPLICA_FETCH_MAX_BYTES=103809024
      - KAFKA_UNCLEAN_LEADER_ELECTION_ENABLE=false
      - KAFKA_MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS=1
      - KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper0.hyperfabric.xyz:2181
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=0
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka0.hyperfabric.xyz:9092
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
      - 9093:9093
```

Running this works fine.

When I introduce another broker using:

```
kafka1.hyperfabric.xyz:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-kafka
  restart: always
  container_name: kafka1.hyperfabric.xyz
  environment:
    - KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES=103809024
    - KAFKA_REPLICA_FETCH_MAX_BYTES=103809024
    - KAFKA_UNCLEAN_LEADER_ELECTION_ENABLE=false
    - KAFKA_MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS=1
    - KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
    - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper0.hyperfabric.xyz:2181
    - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
    - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka1.hyperfabric.xyz:10092
  ports:
    - 10092:9092
    - 10093:9093
```

I get the followin infinitely looping error:

```
[2018-05-11 02:04:08,310] WARN [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=1] Connection to node 1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

The error is somewhat related to my KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS (same thing happens with KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME and KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT) environmental variable. If I remove it, it works, but then my orderers will not receive the brokers address and I will lose communication between orderers and brokers.

How do I maintain the internal connection between my brokers and the external connection to my orderers?

Comment: You are running two brokers on the same host? You better use different disks for your data... Also, are your external clients to `kafka0:9092,kafka1:10092`

Comment: The two brokers on the same host is just temporary as I don't want to spin up more AWS EC2 machines. I am not sure what you mean by your second question, but my orderers are set to look for these brokers on the addresses kafka0.hyperfabric.xyz:9092 and kafka1.hyperfabric.xyz:10092 in their genesis block.

Comment: I don't know what orderers or genesis block means. But the bootstrap servers would need to connect to the brokers using the two ports

Comment: Yep, I believe that is happening as my orderers (clients) are actually initially hitting the cluster using the addresses specified to them (through the genesis block) and are creating a topic which is then being partitioned and replicated. The problem seems to occur after that. My orderers try to then establish a new connection to the brokers (possibly as consumers?) and this new connection was initially pointing to 127.0.0.11:53, which sounds like an internal docker address, and this fails because they are not on the same machine. That's why I added KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS env.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get everything connected by changing my kafka1 container to look like this:

```
kafka1.hyperfabric.xyz:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-kafka
  restart: always
  container_name: kafka1.hyperfabric.xyz
  environment:
    - KAFKA_PORT=10092
    - KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES=103809024
    - KAFKA_REPLICA_FETCH_MAX_BYTES=103809024
    - KAFKA_UNCLEAN_LEADER_ELECTION_ENABLE=false
    - KAFKA_MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS=1
    - KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
    - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper0.hyperfabric.xyz:2181
    - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
    - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka1.hyperfabric.xyz:10092
  ports:
    - 10092:10092
    - 10093:9093
```

The difference being `- KAFKA_PORT=10092` and `- 10092:10092`

Answer (score 2):

Within the container is where your listener variables are configured. 10092 is the port on **your host**, not the container.

Therefore, you want this

```
PLAINTEXT://kafka1.hyperfabric.xyz:9092
```

Along with

```
ports:
    - 10092:9092
```

Or use `10092` for both the listener **and** ports (plus `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT`)

---

Alternatively, if you are on a unix host, you could do `network_mode: host` mode, lose the port forwarding, then you can [use different ports](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/4.0.x/examples/kafka-cluster/docker-compose.yml) for advertised listeners.

Comment: This is making my brokers be able to communicate without the connection to node error but now my orderers (clients) only maintain a connection half the time. ie the 50% chance that kafka0 which is on port 9092 is the leader. The other times I get topic does not exist. I also tested not spinning up kafka0 and only kafka1 with your settings and my orderers spit out an 13.236.69.14:9092: getsockopt: connection refused error, because kafka0 is the one that is on that port, but now isn't active. Doesn't that mean that all that does is redirect everything to kafka0?

Comment: Your point about the port on the host and not the container lead me on the right path. I was able to get it to work using network_mode: host after fixing an error where the second container was using the same port as the first. I forced this using - KAFKA_PORT=10092. I then went back and changed my container around again using that which solved it. I'm thinking this issue might not happen in real scenario with brokers on different machines.